# Qt (sqlite value and QVector<T>::operator[]: "index out of range")

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qvector

I have been writing a program in Qt and i was recently faced by these 2 problems.
Problem 1:
I have a sqlite database with 1 table and 4 columns (id,easy,medium,hard). All ints. So i want to check if the id exist and came up with this code:

```
    QSqlQuery queryCheck(db);
    queryCheck.prepare("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM players WHERE id=':id' LIMIT 1)");
    queryCheck.bindValue(":id", c.getId());
```

But when i run

```
    if(queryCheck.exec())
```

i always get true.

Problem 2:
I have created, and filled with numbers, a

```
QVector<QVector<int>> gridBoxUnsolved(9);
for(int outer=0; outer<gridBoxUnsolved.size(); ++outer)
    gridBoxUnsolved[outer].resize(9);
```

and i want to randomly change some values to 0. I thought about every single "inner" QVector to change 1 random value to 0. So i came up with this code:

```
int iRand;
qsrand(time(NULL));
for (int i=0;i<9;i++){
    iRand = (qrand()%9)+1;
    gridBoxUnsolved[i][iRand]=0;
}
```

However, sometimes Qt works fine, but most of the times crashes and return this: 
        ASSERT failure in QVector::operator[]: "index out of range", file /opt/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qvector.h, line 437
        The program has unexpectedly finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution to the problem.

```
QSqlQuery query(db);
query.prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS N FROM table WHERE id=:id ");
```

and after that you do this to check:

```
query.exec();
query.next();
int N=query.value(0).toInt();
if(N) {
    // You found the record
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
QSqlQuery queryCheck(db);
queryCheck.prepare("SELECT 1 FROM players WHERE id=':id' ");
queryCheck.bindValue(":id", c.getId());

if(queryCheck.exec() && queryCheck.first()) // you found your guy
```

Second problem - remove the +1 in

```
iRand = (qrand()%9)+1;
```

`qrand()%9` will get you a number from 0 to 8 which is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My second problem i see was silly. But with the first one i have a different kind of problem now. I post you the whole code i am trying to achieve:

Comment: if(queryCheck.exec() && queryCheck.first()) {
        qDebug() << "Database: Player Exist (SELECT Working)";
        success = true;
    }
    else if (queryCreate.exec()) {
        qDebug() << "Database: Player Created (INSERT Working)";
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "Database: Error while checking Player: " << queryCheck.lastError();
        qDebug() << "Database: Error while creating Player: " << queryCreate.lastError();
    }
    return success;
}

Comment: so if it finds my guy as you said i want to return 1, if not i want to create him with another query that is correct and working in my code, but it always go to else so i have error from database about unique element (which is correct, because my id is unique)

Comment: What does your `queryCreate` look like?

Comment: QSqlQuery queryCreate(db);
    queryCreate.prepare("INSERT INTO players (id,easy,medium,hard) VALUES (:id,:easy,:medium,:hard)");
    queryCreate.bindValue(":id", c.getId());
    queryCreate.bindValue(":easy", 0);
    queryCreate.bindValue(":medium", 0);
    queryCreate.bindValue(":hard", 0);

Comment: How is `c.getId()` generated?

Comment: This is from the mainwindows.cpp file which i pass the value:
    Player C(insertPass->text().toInt());
    if (db.checkPlayer(C)) .
InsertPass is called my QLineEdit

Comment: How do you ensure that the ID does not exist in the database before you do an INSERT?

Comment: That's what i try to do with queryCheck. If this finds the id i want it to return true, else i want it to create a new entry in the database with this ID.(queryCreate)